# why onclick not alert the props value in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying when I click the table row btn then props values alert the users so when i try to click the row the alert show me undefine

Code:-

```
const Table = ({val}) => {
    const ClickHighlight = (event, id, ChannelName) => {alert(val);}
    return (
      <tbody>
        {!isLoading ? <tr><td>isLoading..</td></tr > : null}
        {PlaylistData && PlaylistData.map((playdata) => {
          return (
            <tr
              key={playdata.idx}
              tabIndex={playdata.idx}
              className="border_bottom"
              onClick = {(e) => ClickHighlight(e, playdata.idx)}
            >
            <td style={{color: "white",width: "440px"}}>
              {playdata.ClipName}
            </td>
          )
        }
```

its also happen in onkeydown when I press enter its show me value but when I click mouse its show me undefine value

Parent Component:-

```
const LeftNav = () => {
 const [page, setPage] = useState("");
      const [ChannelName, setChannelName] = useState([]);
const [getname, linkName] = useState([]);
    function myClick(name, number) {
        linkName(name);
        id = name;
        if (ChannelName[number + 1] !== '' && ChannelName[number + 1] !== null) {
            NextlinkName(ChannelName[number + 1]);
            //alert(`click! ${name} Number ${comments[number + 1]}`);
        }
        if (ChannelName[number + 1] == null) {
            NextlinkName("");
        }
}

return (
  <div>
                    {(ChannelName).map((val, index) => {
                        return (
                            <div className="TextLink" key={index}>
                                <NavLink to={`/`}
                                    onClick={(e) => myClick(val, index)} >
                                    <button className='notActive buttonLeft'
                                        onClick={() =>  setPage("Table") }                                      
                                        className={activeIndex === index ? "active" : "notActive"}>
                                        {val}
                                    </button>
                                </NavLink>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                    }
                </div>
  {page === "Table" ? <Table val={getname} /> : null}
)}
```

[image]

Comment: The variable `val` seems to be coming in from parent-component via props. Can you please post where `Table` component is being rendered (on it's parent) and, please also add `console.log('val at Table is: ', val);` just below this line: `const Table = ({val}) => {` and share what is printed on the console (in dev-tools on the browser).

Comment: update above question

Comment: Okay, so it is possible that `val` may or may not be `undefined`. Now, let us please change `alert(val);` to `console.log('val at ClickHighlight is: ', val);` - see what shows-up in console.

Comment: Please update your code showing where the ChannelName variable comes from. Is it an array, an object?

Comment: val at ClickHighlight is:  undefined show me when i click the row

Answer (score 0):

Your ClickHighlight function is expecting 3 parameters `( event, id, ChannelName)` but you are sending just 2 on the Onclick.

```
onClick={(e) => ClickHighlight(e, playdata.idx)}
```